# JSDB showing error libodbc.so.1 can't be opened

Tags: 19.10, odbc

I am trying to run jsdb in my ubuntu 19.10 machine.

I am getting this error

```
./jsdb: error while loading shared libraries: libodbc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have installed libodbc1 and unixodbc by seeing the error but with no luck. I have searched online but didn't get any relevant answers. So I am posting this question hoping that someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> <sub>error while loading shared libraries: libodbc.so.1: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory</sub>

```
sudo apt install apt-file
apt-file search libodbc.so.1
           ## the reply : libodbc1
sudo apt install libodbc1
```

Comment: I have already installed libodbc1 but it didn't worked.

Comment: Please do `$ file jsdb` to decide if your executable has a different architecture. I.e. could be looking for a 32bits `libodbc.so.1` ?